# Bitrix добавить свое действие

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем привет, как в 1C-Bitrix добавить свое действие в список действий который рядом с кнопками изменить/удалить, чтобы при запуске выполнялся определенный код, как я понял это внутри битрикса нужно писать в коде, но вот где ?

гугл выдал что надо редактировать файл, но что именно редактировать не понял.

```
www/bitrix/modules/iblock/admin/iblock_list_admin.php
```

Answer (score 3):

Лучше всего не модифицировать ядро Битрикс (как вы предлагали изначально), дорабатывая скрипт `/bitrix/modules/iblock/admin/iblock_list_admin.php`.

Более правильный путь - "подвязаться" на события ядра Битрикс.

Используйте событие `OnAdminListDisplay` модуля `main` и создайте свой обработчик этого события в `init.php`.

Вот краткое описание события из официальной документации API:

> Событие `OnAdminListDisplay` вызывается в функции `CAdminList::Display()` при выводе в административном разделе списка элементов. Событие позволяет модифицировать объект списка, в частности, добавить произвольные групповые действия над элементами списка, добавить команды в меню действий элемента списка и т.п.

А вот пример кода из официальной документации API:

```
AddEventHandler("main", "OnAdminListDisplay", "MyOnAdminListDisplay");
function MyOnAdminListDisplay(&$list)
{
    //add custom group action
    if($list->table_id == "tbl_posting")
        $list->arActions["status_draft"] = "Статус: Черновик";
}
//process custom action
AddEventHandler("main", "OnBeforeProlog", "MyOnBeforeProlog");
function MyOnBeforeProlog()
{
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_POST["action"] == "status_draft" && is_array($_POST["ID"]) && $GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetCurPage() == "/bitrix/admin/posting_admin.php")
    {
        if($GLOBALS["APPLICATION"]->GetGroupRight("subscribe") == "W" && check_bitrix_sessid())
        {
            if(CModule::IncludeModule("subscribe"))
            {
                $cPosting = new CPosting;
                foreach($_POST["ID"] as $ID)
                    if(($ID = intval($ID)) > 0)
                        $cPosting->ChangeStatus($ID, "D");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Более подробно о данном событии в документации:
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/events/onadminlistdisplay.php

Статья на эту тему из блога разработчиков Битрикс:
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/webdev/user/11948/blog/2525/